# Open Gallery and file system

Tags: android, gallery

I am trying to open just photos, the function below is opening file manager too and dropbox and drive as well.I need to open just photos. Just gallery.
I also need another function, to open everything other then image.Am seperating between images and  other files.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                                                    intent.setType("image/*");
                                                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                                                    getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: Do not use both ACTION_PICK and ACTION_GET_CONTENT to begin with. Confusing code.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to open just photos

Write your own UI to display photos (e.g., from the `MediaStore`) and allow the user to select one.

> the function below is opening file manager too and dropbox and drive as well

You are delegating to a user-chosen third-party app. That app can do whatever its developers want it to do.

You may have incrementally better luck by getting rid of the `intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);` line.